# Trying to select in console all links that are directing to the specific DOM event. Am I on a good way there?

Tags: javascript, dom

Just playing around here and wanted to know if I am on a good track or not. Why doesn`t this code working? As I said in the title, I want to select all a tags with titles that are related to the events and count them up. Thank you in advance for the explanation!

P.S. Other ways of doing it are welcome, as long as it sticks to vanilla JS and DOM only, no jQuery yet. Thanks!

```js
﻿
﻿

function numberOfEvents {
    var eventsLinks = 0;
    links = document.getElementByTagName('a');

    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].hasAtributeNS("/en-US/docs/Web/Events", "title")) {
            eventsLinks += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it's not working - how? What errors? You've a few misspellings (getElementByTagName, hasAtributeNS), and `numberOfEvents` is missing paranthesis... are these copy errors or your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

Try something simple like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[title*=Events]').length
```

Note: if this is the right answer, the question title really needs rewording.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it going down the path you've specified, but there are shorter ways to do it.  The following is an example.

```js
function numberOfEvents() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('[title="/en-US/docs/Web/Events"]').length;
}

console.log(numberOfEvents());
```

```html
<a href="#" title="/en-US/docs/Web/Events">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" title="No">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" title="/en-US/docs/Web/Events">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" title="No">Link 4</a>
<a href="#" title="/en-US/docs/Web/Events">Link 5</a>
```